# Altium Hierarchical won't Group

Tags: altium

I'm encountering with this new error. As you can see from the pictures below, I can't group schematics.

I created three different grouping methods which are MCU, Inputs and Outputs. Altium chose the last changed one as a grouping and let the other two as different schematics. How may I solve this? Any suggestions please? I'm currently using Altium 23.2.1.

[image: Sheet Tree]

[image: Inside of MCU Sheet Group]

[image: Inside of Outpus Group]

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).